# Parsing calendar event entry like Google Calendar

Tags: python, parsing, google-calendar-api

In Google Calendar, when you click on a date and enter an event, it just asks you to enter something into a text field and it'll automatically interpret what you entered.

So like, I'll enter `dinner at 7PM`, `7PM dinner`, `dinner 7PM`, etc. the app would just understand what it is I'm typing.

How is this done?

Comment: Look at this: http://code.google.com/p/google-diff-match-patch/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's something in PHP: http://blog.builtbyprime.com/php/adding-google-quick-add-to-anything-the-textdate-php-class.

Answer (score 1):

Realize this is an old post, but just in case this is useful for someone: here are some more options/ideas:

#### Option 1: Python

The [`dateutil`](https://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/stable/parser.html) library works quite nicely:

```
>> from dateutil.parser import parse
>> parse("tomrrow at 6pm", fuzzy=True)
Out[14]: datetime.datetime(2016, 11, 10, 18, 0)

>> parse("tomrrow at 6pm", fuzzy_with_tokens=True)
Out[15]: (datetime.datetime(2016, 11, 10, 18, 0), ('tomrrow at ',))
```

#### Option 2: Use the Google Calendar API

This is a bit of a hack, but it should work. You could use [Google Calendar API's quickAdd](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events/quickAdd):

Example request:

```
POST https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/primary/events/quickAdd?text=Peter%2C+tomorrow+at+8am&key={YOUR_API_KEY}
```

Which would return an [Event resource](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events#resource), You could use the data from this object for your needs.

Unfortunately, there doesn't seem to be a way to call `quickAdd` without actually creating an event in a calendar. So you'd kinda need to just have a throw-away Google calendar sitting in the background where the events would get created.